# Order By being ignored in SQL Server 2008 with multiple subqueries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by

I have a report that returns a list of visits made by a patient however the order of visits is completely scrambled.  The list of visits is obtained within a subquery like so:

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT subject_id,
                               A.id [VisitID],
                               A.visit_schedule_id [VisitScheduleID],
                               B.client_visit_description [Visit],
                               visit_date_local [Visit Date],
                               call_date [Call Date]
                FROM tbl_visit A
                INNER JOIN tbl_visit_schedule B ON B.id = A.visit_schedule_id) F
```

There is an inner query that uses this "F" block to grab relevant values to display to the end-user like so:

```
SELECT TOP 9999999999
           A.[name] [Country Name], 
           B.[site_number] [Site Number], 
           D.[investigator_name] [Investigator Name], 
           C.[spid] [Patient Number], 
           E.[YOB] [Year of Birth], 
           F.[Visit] [Visit], 
           CONVERT(NVARCHAR, F.[Visit Date], 120) [Visit Date],
           ISNULL(pl.[Pack(s) Assigned], 'N/A') [Kit Assigned],
           H.[Confirmation (doc)]
    FROM   (
```

And finally there is an outer select which displays to the user:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   [Country Name], 
   [Investigator Name], 
   [Patient Number], 
   [Year of Birth], 
   --[Visit], 
   [Visit Date],
   [Kit Assigned],
   [Confirmation (doc)]
FROM   (
```

I have an ORDER BY for the inner select statement that looks like this:

```
ORDER BY CAST(F.[Visit Date] AS DATE) asc, F.[Call Date] asc
```

The issue is that when I have everything displaying ('Visit' isn't commented out) SQL returns the results in an un-ordered manner, even with the order by at the end.  If I comment out Visit however, the results begin to order.

I'm not sure what significance this one particular column has on the rest of the report that is causing order by to fail, does anyone else have any clues on the matter?

Update: here's the entire query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT site_id, site_number, 
       [Country Name], 
       [Investigator Name], 
       [Patient Number], 
       [Year of Birth], 
       [Visit], 
       [Visit Date],
       [Kit Assigned],
       [Confirmation (doc)]
FROM   (SELECT TOP 99999999999
        B.[id] [site_id], 
               B.[site_number] [site_number], 
               A.[name] [Country Name], 
               B.[site_number] [Site Number], 
               B.[site_number] [SiteNumber], 
               D.[investigator_name] [Investigator Name], 
               C.[spid] [Patient Number], 
               E.[YOB] [Year of Birth], 
               F.[Visit] [Visit], 
               CONVERT(NVARCHAR, F.[Visit Date], 120) [Visit Date],
               ISNULL(pl.[Pack(s) Assigned], 'N/A') [Kit Assigned],
               H.[Confirmation (doc)]
        FROM   (
                SELECT [id], 
                       [name], 
                       [code] [country_code] 
                FROM   [dbo].[tbl_country]) A 
               INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_site] B 
                       ON A.[id] = B.[country_id] 
               INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_subject] C 
                       ON B.[id] = C.[site_id] 
               LEFT JOIN (SELECT A.id, 
                                 A.inv_first_name + ' ' + A.inv_last_name 
                                 [investigator_name] 
                          FROM   vw_site A) D 
                      ON B.[id] = D.[id] 
               INNER JOIN (SELECT A.[subject_id], 
                                  B.int_value [YOB] 
                           FROM   vw_subject_info A 
                                  INNER JOIN tbl_custom_data B 
                                          ON B.row_id = A.subject_id 
                                             AND B.table_name = 'Subject' 
                                             AND B.[field_name] = 'Initial_DOB') 
                          E 
                       ON C.[id] = E.[subject_id] 
               INNER JOIN (
                            SELECT subject_id,
                                   VisitID,
                                   VisitScheduleID,
                                   site_id,
                                   site_number,
                                   visit [Visit],
                                   visit_date_local [Visit Date],
                                   call_date [Call Date]
                            FROM vw_visit
                           ) F 
                       ON C.[id] = F.[subject_id] 
              LEFT JOIN (SELECT [visit_id],
                          [int_value] [Confirmation (doc)]
                          FROM  [vw_visitDetail]
                          WHERE  [field_name] = 'docId'
                          ) H
                      ON F.[VisitID] = H.[visit_id]
              --Selecting the packs dispensed at latest dispensing visit              
               LEFT JOIN (SELECT A.[id] [visit_id],
               STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(C.[client_pack_number] AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
                      FROM   [dbo].[tbl_visit_pack] B
                      INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_pack] C
                      ON B.[pack_id] = C.[id]
                      INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_pack_type pt
                      ON pt.id = c.pack_type_id
                      WHERE  A.[id] = B.[visit_id]    
                      FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS [Pack(s) Assigned]
               FROM   [dbo].[tbl_visit] A
               GROUP  BY A.[id]) pl
               ON pl.visit_id = F.visitid
               --Ordering
               ORDER BY CAST(F.[Visit Date] AS DATE) asc, F.[Call Date] asc
) rawquery 
--where
```

Comment: you `Order by ` in outer query

Comment: try put the order by F.Visit Date in your sub query

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar I can't put it in the outer query unfortunately since I'm implementing this within a framework that does a few specific things that precludes using an order by in the outer query.

Comment: @Steve I've attempted ordering the sub query in that way and while the sub query will return the results in an ordered manner, the final result still comes out un-ordered.

Comment: how about try to alias the result table of your sub query and order by that?

Comment: We can show how to do this if you can post the entire query instead of parts and pieces.

Comment: @Sean Lange I've updated the OP with the entire query

Comment: The only reliable way of getting an order of results is to put the desired `order by` on the outermost query. Anything else is certainly not guaranteed. If the order by is important you'll need to use a framework that allows this.

Answer (score 1):

To get your output in a specific order you need to add an order by after your "rawquery" alias. As it sits right now your query has no order by so you have no way of knowing what order the results will be.

```
SELECT DISTINCT site_id
                , site_number
                , [Country Name]
                , [Investigator Name]
                , [Patient Number]
                , [Year of Birth]
                , [Visit]
                , [Visit Date]
                , [Kit Assigned]
                , [Confirmation (doc)]
FROM   (SELECT TOP 99999999999 B.[id]                                   [site_id]
                               , B.[site_number]                        [site_number]
                               , A.[name]                               [Country Name]
                               , B.[site_number]                        [Site Number]
                               , B.[site_number]                        [SiteNumber]
                               , D.[investigator_name]                  [Investigator Name]
                               , C.[spid]                               [Patient Number]
                               , E.[YOB]                                [Year of Birth]
                               , F.[Visit]                              [Visit]
                               , CONVERT(NVARCHAR, F.[Visit Date], 120) [Visit Date]
                               , Isnull(pl.[Pack(s) Assigned], 'N/A')   [Kit Assigned]
                               , H.[Confirmation (doc)]
        FROM   (SELECT [id]
                       , [name]
                       , [code] [country_code]
                FROM   [dbo].[tbl_country]) A
               INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_site] B
                       ON A.[id] = B.[country_id]
               INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_subject] C
                       ON B.[id] = C.[site_id]
               LEFT JOIN (SELECT A.id
                                 , A.inv_first_name + ' ' + A.inv_last_name [investigator_name]
                          FROM   vw_site A) D
                      ON B.[id] = D.[id]
               INNER JOIN (SELECT A.[subject_id]
                                  , B.int_value [YOB]
                           FROM   vw_subject_info A
                                  INNER JOIN tbl_custom_data B
                                          ON B.row_id = A.subject_id
                                             AND B.table_name = 'Subject'
                                             AND B.[field_name] = 'Initial_DOB') E
                       ON C.[id] = E.[subject_id]
               INNER JOIN (SELECT subject_id
                                  , VisitID
                                  , VisitScheduleID
                                  , site_id
                                  , site_number
                                  , visit            [Visit]
                                  , visit_date_local [Visit Date]
                                  , call_date        [Call Date]
                           FROM   vw_visit) F
                       ON C.[id] = F.[subject_id]
               LEFT JOIN (SELECT [visit_id]
                                 , [int_value] [Confirmation (doc)]
                          FROM   [vw_visitDetail]
                          WHERE  [field_name] = 'docId') H
                      ON F.[VisitID] = H.[visit_id]
               --Selecting the packs dispensed at latest dispensing visit
               LEFT JOIN (SELECT A.[id]                                [visit_id]
                                 , Stuff((SELECT ', '
                                                 + Cast(C.[client_pack_number] AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
                                          FROM   [dbo].[tbl_visit_pack] B
                                                 INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_pack] C
                                                         ON B.[pack_id] = C.[id]
                                                 INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_pack_type pt
                                                         ON pt.id = c.pack_type_id
                                          WHERE  A.[id] = B.[visit_id]
                                          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS [Pack(s) Assigned]
                          FROM   [dbo].[tbl_visit] A
                          GROUP  BY A.[id]) pl
                      ON pl.visit_id = F.visitid --Ordering 
        ORDER  BY Cast(F.[Visit Date] AS DATE) ASC
                  , F.[Call Date] ASC
) rawquery 
--where
Order By YourColumnHere
```

Comment: I have to ask...what is the point of selecting the top 10 billion rows in a subquery? Does your table really have more rows than that and you want to make sure they are ordered? Do you realize that ordering a subquery like this is really pointless?

Comment: The top 10 billion rows is a hack I read about elsewhere (http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/08/23/sql-server-order-by-does-not-work-limitation-of-the-views-part-1/) that is supposed to help overcome the limitation of being able to order by in a view.  I know it's bad coding practice and all, but I really wanted to get the ordering working.  As adding the order by to the outer query is not possible for me, I will have to accept that ordering is not possible.  Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: As you said that is a hack. It also doesn't work anymore. Even worse is that it never worked if you had views in a query that used that same hack. Which order by would be honored?